# Tripadvisor offer the same price regardless of how many people use the hotel room. How can this be true?

Tags: budget, online-resources, bookings

I would like to ask everyone here if they can shed some light on the way Tripadvisor's discounts work. While looking for private houses for 2 people I found an option that seems to let me book for 1 or 2 people at the same price (that is 20€/night).

I wondered if the "91% discount" tag had something to do with it, as the website for the location states that the price starts from 21€/night **per person**.

Indeed if I start the booking procedure, the recap says "2 guests" and states the total as calculated with 20€/night even with twice the guests. (Let's ignore the 500£ deposit for right this second).

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is this legit or should I expect them to ask me more money at a later stage? Should I be worried about my deposit if I take this opportunity?
Thanks!

Comment: I would say the best thing to do is to contact the place of lodging itself and clarify their policies. Usually they prefer you book directly through them anyway, as it saves them money, but it's not clear to me exactly what kind of "private houses" you're talking about. Are these Flipkey listings? Third-party booking sites are notorious for having mislabeled details like this and it can lead to a lot of problems when people think they've booked one thing and the hotel thinks something else.

Comment: It may well be that the price is the same for two as it is for one, just like many hotel rooms that have a 'room price'. So the price will not change when adding the second person.

Comment: Same price for one or two people is very common but where is this accommodation? If €20 is really cheap for the area/standard of lodging (and it would be in large parts of the eurozone), I would be careful.

Comment: Another common system (if you rent a whole cottage or gite for a week or more, not for hotel rooms) is to pay a fixed price to rent the place (no matter how many people will use it) and then a per-person fee (for bed sheets, towels, etc.). That fee would be paid once of the stay (not per night) and you might or might not be able to opt out of it (by bringing your own towels, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the area you're booking your hotel at. For example, the vast majority of US hotels only post rates per room, not per person. So as long as room max occupancy limit is not exceeded, your price will not change.

Same happens even in Europe if you are single, but try to book a double room/room with a double bed. Those rooms are typically priced for two people, but they will not give you a discount for one person. Thus you see no price difference whether you book for one or two. Could be the same case with your private housing.

Comment: (+1) Not sure the OP is contemplating a hotel, self-catering vacation/cottage rentals sometimes work slightly differently (feel free to use my comment above to expand your answer if you wish).

Comment: Good point. I just wasn't sure TripAdvisor has those too, as the OP asked about TripAdvisor "pricing".